# Diagnosing iOS C++ / Objective C++ calls from Swift in Xcode

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, swift, objective-c++

I have some legacy C++ that I call using an Objective C++ bridge from a Swift iOS app.

I first built a simple test app (basically just the C++ call with limited UX around it). In this test app the C++ takes between 0.4 and 1.4 seconds to complete, as measured naively using this pattern:

```swift
let startedAt:NSDate = NSDate()
self.callOutToCPlusPlus(loads:of, passedIn:values)
print("CPlusPlus done in \(NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(startedAt)) seconds")
```

Now I have added the same code used in the test app to the full app where it takes 3.5 seconds. How do I diagnose the slow down?

Comment: Your question isn't really clear in it's current state. What does "diagnosing the performance loss" mean? Are you trying to find out why it's slower in the app vs however you were testing it outside of the app?

Comment: Exactly - code in simple test app takes 0.4 - 1.4 seconds, but the same code in the full app takes 3.5 seconds. I do not know how to diagnose the slow down.

Comment: (N.B. I have [asked this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/101520) over on the Apple Developper Forums too

Answer (score 1):

A few ideas:

1) Is the legacy code built as part of the Xcode project?  If so, you may be able to use Xcode's profiling capabilities to see where the slowdown is.
2) Do you use the same optimization level in your test and full apps?
3) Do you pass the same data to the legacy code in both apps?

Hopefully this helps.